# How to select dynamically column from the table?

Tags: sql

I wrote a trigger for a table for insert ,update. For every insert and
update, in the trigger I am comparing rows from 'Inserted' table and rows
from 'Deleted' table.

I need to get the affected column. How to do this?

```
A B C D
1 2 3 5.
```

I am updating B's value with 3. Then the trigger will fire. In that trigger,
from deleted table I can get :

```
A B C D
1 2 3 5
```

From the Inserted table I can get:

```
A B C D
1 3 3 5
```

I need to get the column B alone.

How to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Actually A,B,C,D are columns and 1,2,3,4 are values. I wrote like a table but it didn't display like that. Please dont confuse.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can check whether or not a column has changed by IF UPDATE(namehere)

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Triggername]
ON [dbo].[TableName]
FOR UPDATE
AS 

IF UPDATE(Columname) --If this column has changed
BEGIN
       --Your code here
    END
```

Comment: hah, I was half way through a long answer containing a horrible CASE statement. Had forgotton about UPDATE() func. Good answering.